# How to remove layout_marginStart programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout

As the title described i want to remove a `TypefacedTextView`'s `layout_marginStart` from the code.

**layout.xml**

```
android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you can do this by using following code

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) tv.getLayoutParams();
params.setMarginStart(0);
tv.setLayoutParams(params);
```

You can replace **LinearLayout.LayoutParams** with as per your requirment, depends on **parent of your textview**. If it is **RelativeLayout** then replace **LinearLayout** with this one. And same for other type of parent.

Comment: 2nd line should be params.setMarginStart(0); also last line should be params not buttonLayoutParams.

Comment: In my case I had to cast to [ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams)  instead of LinearLayout.LayoutParams for it to work.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this code to save other layout params:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams textLayoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) textView.getLayoutParams();
textLayoutParams.setMarginStart(0);
textView.setLayoutParams(buttonLayoutParams);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `lp.setMarginStart(int start)`